# div mouseenter show and stay in focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show a inner div when mouseenter and hide on mouseleave. i use jquery hover to get done that.my problems are

1. when mouseenter inner div's controls shows from collapsed state.
2. when i use inner div select (dropdown) it get lost focus.

how can i fixed those issues

here is my html

```
<div id="outter" class="outter">
 <h1>hover me</h1>

<div id="inner" class="inner">
    <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>
        <option>8</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

and my javascript

```
var outter = $("#outter");
var inner = $("#inner");
inner.stop(true, true).hide();
outter.hover(function (e) {
    inner.toggle(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            height: 10
        }, 200);
    });
});
```

please i'm looking for any advices

[**JS Fiddler Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7pLEK/)

**updated**
i need something to get look like this

http://realestate.mysanantonio.com/

but when i'm doing mouseover/mouseenter continualsly i don't want to fire all the events.
so i used

```
inner.stop(true, true).hide();
```

that code to stop that on my original code but still i'm looking for advices

thanks

Comment: Google jquery hover :) It requires two params, first is a function on mouseeneter, second is function on mouse leave :)

Comment: @Mr.TK Not necessary to use two params...

Comment: I'm a little confused on what the issue is. When I select the dropdown list, it seems to show fine and the hover stays there for me. Is that not what it's designed to do?

Comment: I would create two classes and when you hover over an element is simply removed one class and assigned to the second. All animation implemented would css

Comment: Zhouster try by selecting dropdown and after get away from select box and to select option. thanks

Comment: You might be able to solve the issue but I would call it a poor design choice as the dropdown is coming out of your container.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
.inner {
    background-color:rgba(183, 17, 17, 0.6);
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    display: none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var stopHiding = false;

outter.mouseenter(function (e) {
    inner.show(function () {
        inner.animate({
            height: 20
        }, 200);
    });
});

outter.mouseleave(function () {
    if (!stopHiding) {
        inner.hide();
    } else {
        stopHiding = false;
    }
});

$('select').change(function () {
    stopHiding = true;
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7pLEK/7/)

Comment: Can you select any option from the dropdown?

Comment: alexP what about mouseleave??

Comment: hi alexP, thanks for the reply but seems to be it's not working correctly. i have updated your demo with height in inner div check this out.
http://jsfiddle.net/gayancc/7pLEK/8/

Comment: i have came up with solution like this if somebody can solve the hide issue. (only hide if not focused inner child element) http://jsfiddle.net/7pLEK/10/